# Filtering unique records from a table meeting criteria in three related tables

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having trouble in Access 2010 filtering records meeting criteria from three possible tables all linked by a common `FormulationID`.

A simplified description is

- I have a table called `tblFormulation` with a `FormulationID` key and fields describing who created it, general characteristics, formulation date, etc.  I will need to filter on some of these fields.  Most of the fields I will display are in this table.
- Linked through `FormulationID` is a second table, `tblComponents`, which includes all the components, their type, and volumes.  Each `FormulationID` has 4-7 components.  I want to select `FormulationsIDs` by Component and/or Type.  I only need to know which `FormulationIDs` meet the criteria.  I am not displaying any of these fields.
- Also linked through FormulationID is a third table called `tblApprovals`.  Let's think of this as `Authorites` who have published different Levels of Approval for these formulations.  Again, I want to select `FormulationsIDs` by Approvals and/or `Authorites`.  Each `Forumulation` can have 1 to 30 Approvals.  I only need to know which `FormulationIDs` meet the criteria.  I am not displaying any of these fields.  Editing of Components and Approvals takes place on separate forms that are called up after a formulation is selected.

I have tried two approaches to generate a list of Formulations and general characteristics containing selected components with certain selected approvals.

- First, I have created queries with criteria for each leg.  Let's call them `qryComponents` and `qryApprovals`.  These each produce a listing of `FormulationIDs` filtered for the criteria.  Access won't let me just do a Join on these with `tblFormulation` in a final query due to **'Ambiguous Outer Joins'** issue so I wind up creating an intermediate query, qryStep2, with `tblFormulation` records only found in `qryApprovals`.  I then join that in a final query, `qryFiltered`, with the `tblFormulation` records found in `qryComponents`.
  I then use `qryFiltered` as the `recordsournce` for `frmFiltered` which includes comboboxes for criteria in `tblFormulations` and `qryComponents` and `qryApprovals`.  **In theory this should work.  In reality, it doesn't.**  I change the comboboxes and requery the form, but it doesn't requery the underlying three queries.  I use VBA and haven't figured out if there is a way to requery the underlying queries so the cascade gives me the final desired listing of filtered formluations.  So the question on this solution is how can I get the after_update subroutine for `frmFiltered.cboApprovals` to force the four requeries - or is  there another solution?
- After failing with this solution, I tried the heavy-duty VBA approach.  I created a single query, `qryEverything`, with all the fields from all the tables.  This gives me a FormulationID record with each formulation Approval and still another of the combined records for every Component.  There are a lot of records.  I then set up `frmFilter` with comboboxes and a subForm of the fields I want.  The after update event on the comboboxes triggers modifications to the WHERE clause of the `qryEverything` SQL statement which I use for the recordset for subForm.  This works, but I have repeated FormulationIDs where a single formulation meets criteria in both the Component and Approval legs.  I thought I could use `SELECT UNIQUE on FormulationID` after the filtering, but it's before the `WHERE` clause so the filtering doesn't work.  I really need to be able to do a second `SELECT UNIQUE` on this recordset.  I guess I could step through it and delete repeats.  Doesn't sound right.

So I'm stuck.  I'll keep playing, but could really use some help.

Answer (score 1):

re: *Access won't let me just do a Join on these with tblFormulation in a final query due to "Ambiguous Outer Joins"*

Try using a left outer join from `tblFormulation` to `qryComponents` using all rows from `tblFormulation` and a second left outer join from `tblFormulation` to `qryApprovals` again, with all the rows from `tblFormulation`.

That should be all you need.  If you only want formulations with at least one component and approval, use inner joins instead of outer.

If you're still having problems, post your SQL.

Comment: I think this can be done and I'll give it a try.  I think that will address the four query issue, but won't I still wind up with three queries (qryComponents, qryFormulations and the new qryFiltered)?  When the combobox  modify the criteria in  qryComponents or qryFormulations the requery on frmFiltered will still only requery qryFiltered, not the underlying qryComponents and qryFormulations.  The big problem with this nested query solution is getting the early queries to update with the new criteria so the final query shows the formulations meeting the criteria.  Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: have you tried it?  It should refresh the query you're displaying including all its underlying queries.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the real challenge is going to be in building the WHERE clause

I think as a query, this would work

```
dim strsql1 = _
"SELECT tblformulation.*, tblcomponents.FormulationID, tblcomponents.FormulationID  FROM tblformulation AS a JOIN tblcomponents as B ON  a.FormulationID = b.FormulationID JOIN tblComponents as c ON a.FormulationID = c.FormulationID WHERE " & strwhere & ";")
```

And then Select Distinct a.FormulationID from there and voila

Answer (score 0):

With help I found the answer and learned something. While I said I needed only fields from frmFormulatins I included others to see results. This created redundant unique records.

Final query: SELECT DISTINCT tblFormulation.FormulationID, tblFormulation.SponsorCode, tblFormulation.AddCo, tblFormulation.Application FROM tblComponent RIGHT JOIN (tblApprovals RIGHT JOIN tblFormulation ON tblApprovals.FormulationID = tblFormulation.FormulationID) ON tblComponent.FormulationID = tblFormulation.FormulationID WHERE (((tblApprovals.Authority)="API") AND ((tblComponent.BOGrp)="Grp III"));

I also learned to post code - it makes it a lot clearer.  First question.  Thanks all